# date not incrementing with AddDays(1)

Tags: c#

I'm writing a loop that go through all the week. It looks like this:

```
DateTime TheDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-365);

while(TheDate.Date <= DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
{
    TheDate.AddDays(1);

    if (TheDate.DayOfWeek == 5 || TheDate.DayOfWeek == 6)
    {
        continue;
    }
 
    SomeMethod(TheDate);
}
```

The problem is that `TheDate` never gets incremented. Why is that and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AddDays` returns new instance of `DateTime`, so:

```
TheDate = TheDate.AddDays(1);
```